# django sort on another column instead of clicked column in change list

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Simplifying the model, suppose we have:

```
class Model(model.Models):
  date = models.DateField()
  date_representation = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Date')
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('date_representation',)
```

when we click date_representation(verbose name 'date') in the change list , at the back it should sort by date.
I know this can be done by a custom method with admin_order_field_by, but i want to avoid the additional cost of accessing the method if possible.
Is there any way this could be done.